# What OAuth scopes do I need to query in order to work with the service hook REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

For example, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/hooks/subscriptions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) method.
The documentation now only says that it is possible to access this API via PAT (see [security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/hooks/subscriptions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#security) section)
But in practice I tried to create an application requesting 'vso.work_full' and 'vso.identity' and later I was able to use the above API (managed to create a subscription), via the received token. Is it a bug? If not, then why the documentation doesn't contain explicit mentioning of the scopes required for this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What OAuth scopes do I need to query in order to work with the service
> hook REST API?

For this issue, we can query the scope related to the service hook in the [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#scopes) document. For example:

[image]

The document does not list all authentication methods. You can submit this feedback for [azure-devops-docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/new?title=&body=%0A%0A%5BEnter%20feedback%20here%5D%0A%0A%0A---%0A%23%23%23%23%20Document%20Details%0A%0A%E2%9A%A0%20*Do%20not%20edit%20this%20section.%20It%20is%20required%20for%20learn.microsoft.com%20%E2%9E%9F%20GitHub%20issue%20linking.*%0A%0A*%20ID%3A%20ac47cbcf-45ed-81aa-b532-e7ad0046658e%0A*%20Version%20Independent%20ID%3A%207aa1f60e-069f-3d62-5cac-b65e4b1116ef%0A*%20Content%3A%20%5BAuthorization%20using%20OAuth%202.0%20-%20Azure%20DevOps%5D(https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fintegrate%2Fget-started%2Fauthentication%2Foauth%3Fview%3Dazure-devops)%0A*%20Content%20Source%3A%20%5Bdocs%2Fintegrate%2Fget-started%2Fauthentication%2Foauth.md%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FMicrosoftDocs%2Fazure-devops-docs%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fdocs%2Fintegrate%2Fget-started%2Fauthentication%2Foauth.md)%0A*%20Product%3A%20**devops**%0A*%20Technology%3A%20**devops-ecosystem**%0A*%20GitHub%20Login%3A%20%40chcomley%0A*%20Microsoft%20Alias%3A%20**chcomley**).